# Controlling an old servo with arduino

Tags: arduino, servo, linear

as part of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/253722/powering-an-old-rc-servo-cant-find-the-datasheet) old thread, I started trying using an old RC servo with arduino.

The one I used (Sanwa SRM 102) has a torque of about 3kg\cm and operates with 5V. I used an external power supply for the servo and made the wiring with the little material I found out on the web. The wires are RED-BLACK-BLACK and it seem to be +-\Signal.

This is the scheme:

[image]
The problem appears when I try to upload my sketch. The servo tries to push as much as possible forward, forcing and I need to power off it.

Using the "Servo" library, the problem appears whatever I write in the myservo.write(x) statement, and tries to reach always the same position.

I made a little video to show you what I mean:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDvquFk9CZE

Maybe being and old servo it uses some different communication protocol?

What can I try?

This is my semplified sketch:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define SERVO_PIN 9

Servo myservo;



void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);

}

void loop()
{

 myservo.write(0);
 delay(5000);
 myservo.write(30);
  delay(5000);
  myservo.write(50);
  delay(5000);
  myservo.write(90);

}
```

EDIT: As suggested, it was just a problem of common gnd.

Comment: have you connected the ground of arduino with ground of battery?

Comment: It would probably help if you connect the servo power with the same polarity as the battery power.

Comment: that was an error with the scheme, it was obviously connected correctly, otherwise it woudn't have moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program looks fine to me. However, i am not able to see any connection connecting `Ground` of battery with `ground` of `arduino`.

It is very important as there are two different circuits (one is your arduino and other is your servo connected with battery) in your project communicating with a single wire which delivers signal in `pulse width modulation` form(servo signal). The circuits should agree on same `voltage reference` which can be achieved by connecting ground of two circuits together.